# Page not showing login window on enter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

Hello I have webpage which uses Windows authentication. 
It is working well in

- IE
- Chrome
- Opera

and not working in

- Firefox

In Firefox and opera when I try enter my page modal window appears asking for windows login and password. When I input them I can browse my page. In Chrome and IE I don't need to do anything.
For me its strange.

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using magazyn.Models;
using magazyn.Autorization;
using System.Text;
namespace magazyn.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private EquipmentEntities db = new EquipmentEntities();
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Error401()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
}
```

As You can see ther is `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute so why Firefox and Opera demands login and password to enter the page?

@Update:
I check IIS config. Anonous Authentication is enabled.

Comment: What type of authentication you got?

Comment: Windows authentication. One of an option from Visual studio project wizard. But on the Home/Index as you see is no authentitcation used. This page is open for anonymous

Comment: You should check the IIS settings if you allow anonymous, because it is problem on IIS not in your code

Comment: If this is problem with IIS so why this page is working in all browsers but Firefox?

Comment: Chrome and IE has build in Windows authentication support. Firefox doesn't

Comment: Check IIS Allow Anonymous Enabled

Comment: Okay may be this is also a problem.When your Cookies are disabled (blocked all cookies).  you can get this kind of prob. im not saying its only because of this but may be. To test Just Login for your gmail account in MOzilla. if its working fine then this may not be the answer but if its not logging in Then this will work definately

Answer (score 0):

Ok found solution. 
I needed to follow this steps:

- Open Firefox
- In the Address bar type about:config
- In the search/filter field type ntlm
- Set network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris to .company_name.com
- Set network.automatic-ntlm-auth.allow-non-fqdn to true by right-clicking and selecting "toggle"
- In the search/filter field type negotiate
- Set network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris to .company_name.com
- Set network.negotiate-auth.allow-non-fqdn to true by right-clicking and selecting "toggle"
- Click OK if present
- Restart Firefox.

Quite simply but now I need to tell this to all  users using FF or tell them to change browser... It's strange that them didnt' implement windows auth like other browsers